# Strange SHL operation in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, bit-shift

What's wrong with `v:=v shl b`? I'm trying to calculate *mask* = 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1 like `mask:=1 shl n-1`, but fails for integer variable n=64.

```
program UInt64Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  u,v,w:uint64;
const
  a=64;
var
  b:integer=a;
  c:integer=a-1;

begin
  u:=1; v:=1; w:=1;
  u:=u shl a;
  v:=v shl b;
  w:=w shl 1 shl c;
  writeln(u);
  writeln(v);
  writeln(w);
  readln;
end.
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
```

I suspected `v` to be zero too.

Solved like `2 shl (n-1)-1`. In this case compiler perform machine `shl` (not `__llshl`):

```
function reciprocal(o:uint64;n:byte=64):uint64; // result * o = 1 (mod 2ⁿ)
var
  b,m,t:uint64;
begin
  result:=0;
  t:=2 shl (n-1)-1;
  m:=0; b:=1;
  while b<>0 do begin
    m:=m or b;
    if ((o*result) and m)<>1 then result:=result or b;
    b:=(b shl 1) and t;
  end;
end;
```

... but, I'm not happy.

Comment: Try to use `v := v shl UInt64(b);`

Comment: Stepping into the `__llshl` function called, reveals that b is masked with $3F. This means the the shift operation is done with a zero. And result will be 1.

Comment: @valex, this gives 1 as well.

Comment: Until D2010, `__llshl` performs a shift for n=64 -> the result is 0 and it was different from machine instruction. Now with mask $3F it was fixed, but not in the Delphi optimizer, which still performs shift in case `u := u shl a` and still assigns 0.

Comment: There's a bug here. Calculations with constants, that are performed by compiler, should match the calculations performed at runtime. Is this fixed in the latest Delphi, or do we need to QC it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my answer is tested with XE3 and matches documentation. Very disturbing. Same on cardinal 1 shl 32.

Comment: @LU RD, have you tested it with constant? Looking into code in XE3, the compiler still xors edx,eax i.e. performs shift

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've tested it on XE3 (17.0.4723.55752) and there is still the bug i.e code produced by compiler does not match __llshl functionality.

Comment: .55752 is XE3 update 1, XE3 update 2 (just out) is 17.0.4770.56661 You might want to try that one too, although there's nothing in the fix list regarding your issue http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42863

Comment: @Jan Doggen: maybe some time, because I do not use XE3 yet and currently I don't have a time to upgrade it.

Answer (score 11):

From the [`documentation`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Example) :

> The operations x shl y and x shr y shift the value of x to the left or right by y bits, which (if x is an unsigned integer) is equivalent to multiplying or dividing x by 2^y; the result is of the same type as x. For example, if N stores the value 01101 (decimal 13), then N shl 1 returns 11010 (decimal 26). **Note that the value of y is interpreted modulo the size of the type of x. Thus for example, if x is an integer, x shl 40 is interpreted as x shl 8 because an integer is 32 bits and 40 mod 32 is 8**.

So 1 shl 64 on a 64 bit value is interpreted as 1 shl 0 which is 1.

```
const
  aa = 32;
var
  x,y,z : Cardinal;
...
x := 1;
y := 32;
z := x shl aa; // Gives z = 1
z := x shl 32; // Gives z = 1
z := x shl y;  // Gives z = 1;
```

So it seems that there is a compiler bug for 64 bit values when y is a constant.

Note in 64 bit mode, 1 shl 64 results in 1.

So the bug is only in the 32 bit compiler.

Reported as [`QC112261 SHL operations by constant fails`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=112261).

---

If the wanted result of your shift operation was 0 for a y value >= 64,
then this function can be used:

```
function ShiftLeft( AValue : UInt64; bits : Integer) : UInt64; inline;
begin
  if (bits > 63) then 
    Result := 0 // Avoid bits being modified modulo 64
  else
    Result := AValue shl bits;
end;
```

---

**Update**

This compiler bug is resolved in version XE4.

Comment: That explains half of the story. But why doesn't the compiler use the same rules when evaluating constant expressions at compile time? Does it still get those wrong in XE3? Both 32 and 64 bit compilers?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, 64 bit compiler is ok.

Comment: The 32-bit compiler (XE) generates compile-time error if shift constant is out of bounds but does not generate runtime range checks: `{$R+}
var
  J: Integer;
  I: Integer;

begin
  I:= 1;
  J:= 40;
  Writeln(I, I shl J);  // no range error generated
  readln;
end.`

Comment: @Leif What does the RD stand for? And +1 for the answer and QC report. Well done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm the R&D manager for my company. My work involves optical/mechanical constructions as well a software engineering in the area of building systems for gas and particle monitoring. Lasers/Interferometers/Spectrometers are my daily line of work. Incredible amounts of man-years is built into our software for data collections/presentation coupled to GIS-models meteorology and forcasting/nowcasting.

Comment: Srba, you mention that you are not happy. Is my `ShiftLeft` function not what you want?

Comment: It now shows the status of your report as `Resolved`, but I can't see where it shows *in what way* it was resolved (as in `Fixed`, `Won't Fix` etc.). Do you happen to know that? Or does `Resolved` actually *mean* `Fixed` in their reporting system?

Comment: @AndriyM, it means it has passed their internal checks and will be incorporated in their next update, hopefully XE3 update 3. Never seen such a quick fix before though.

Comment: A silly, facepalm kind of mistake, perhaps. Or maybe something completely different: "You see? I told you they would notice. I won, now give me my 20$." :) Just joking. And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AndriyM, it must have been embarrassing, since the `shl` operator is the same since the Turbo Pascal days. Any serious unit test would have revealed the dysfunction.